# How to add custom JS code on review-order page in woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

This is the previous question related to this topic: [Stripe JS element disappering in WooCommerce Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65792332/stripe-js-element-disappering-in-woocommerce-checkout)

So after i played a little bit i somehow managed to get the fields like this and its validating as well.

But the problem is i inserted the JS code in this file: ***wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php***

[image]

### **This is how it looks:**

[image]

### This is the JS code that was added:

```
<script>
    (function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Create a Stripe client.
        var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_51IB3etJxogSn2Fj0hqBSBcCkGH76cUowa9iWK7Xm7gj3O2jdt8FfcIXrHoZGIk4ySL1MyYYp1IxN582FOsjgI1DD00Hr7nvVF1');

// Create an instance of Elements.
        var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
        var style = {
            base: {
                color: '#32325d',
                fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
                fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
                fontSize: '16px',
                '::placeholder': {
                    color: '#aab7c4'
                }
            },
            invalid: {
                color: '#fa755a',
                iconColor: '#fa755a'
            }
        };

// Create an instance of the card Element.
        var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-number` <div>.
        card.mount('#card-number');
// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
        card.on('change', function (event) {
            var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            if (event.error) {
                displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
            } else {
                displayError.textContent = '';
            }
        });

// Handle form submission.
// var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
// form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
//   event.preventDefault();
//
//   stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
//     if (result.error) {
//       // Inform the user if there was an error.
//       var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
//       errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
//     } else {
//       // Send the token to your server.
//       stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
//     }
//   });
// });

// Submit the form with the token ID.
// function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
//   // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
//   var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
//   var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
//   hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
//   hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
//   hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
//   form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
//
//   // Submit the form
//   form.submit();
// }
    });
})(this.jQuery);



</script>
```

So my question is how can i prioritize/enqueue this JS code properly so that it works from my plugin and not just copying and pasting the code in woocommerce template.

This is how i am enqueuing my scripts:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array(self::class, 'enqueue'), 100, 1);

 // add js in wordpress frontend
    public static function enqueue()
    {
        wp_enqueue_script('woocommerce_pay_later_stripe_script', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/', array('jquery'), false, true);
        wp_enqueue_script('woocommerce_pay_later_main_script', plugins_url('/assets/main.js', __DIR__), array('jquery'), false, true);
    }
```

Comment: create a plugin for your snippet

Comment: @mehmoodkhan i am creating a plugin to create a custom payment gateway already. I have achieved the creation of payment gateway but i want strip js elements when that payment gateway is selected or shown. The problem is in managing JS i have put the script in payment_fields() method and it works, but i want to know the correct way of doing instead of just putting the code here and there.

Answer (score 0):

You could enqueue your script just in that specific page!

First find the id of you review-order page and then check whether you're on that page or not. If you're are, then load your script!

The following code will go to the functions.php of your active theme or the active child theme.

```
function loading_your_custom_js(){

$order_review_page_id = ; #assign the id of your page to the variable here - You could find that id in the admin area under pages section

# check whether you're on the review-order page or not

  if(get_the_ID() == $order_review_page_id){
    wp_enqueue_script('checkout_js', 'your_custom_script.js', 'JQuery', '1.0', TRUE);
  };
};

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loading_your_custom_js');
```

Comment: I dont want to put it into functions.php i want everything to be managed from my custom plugin. Also if i hardcode the pageID inside $order_review_page_id variable and if it doesn't matches the condition won't work.

Comment: You could absolutely use the same logic in your plugin files and when you activate your plugin it'll get included in your functions.php file. It's very easy to do. Just check whether you're on that page or not, then load your script into the page. For the second question, well yes that's right, if the condition isn't met, meaning you're not in the review-order page and the code won't load, that's what you wanted isn't it?

Comment: doesn't work. there is no order-review page in admin section, but checkout page. https://prnt.sc/xarvwj its page id is 8 and i put your code in activate method. Went and reactivate the plugin and went to the checkout page. nothing happens.  :-/

Comment: I see! Well, the only thing I could think of right now is your javascript code. I see that you're using jquery ```$``` right? Have you ever used jquery in the wordpress environment? Loading and using jquery in wordpress has a slightly different approach than a normal page...